# How to get more junit-failed-details in gradle log without running gradle in debug mode

Tags: logging, gradle, junit, reporting, travis-ci

Question:

Is there a way to add the details of failed junit4 tests to gradle output witout making all of gradle more verbose?

Background:

I have a java-se junit4 regression test for handling ical content that works fine on my win-7-64 local machine but 
that fails on travis-ci buildserver using gradle.

when i run

```
./gradlew assemble libIcsJ2se:test
```

the gradle output from travis-ci log contains this

```
* What went wrong:

Execution failed for task ':libIcsJ2se:test'.

> There were failing tests. See the report at: 
> file:///home/travis/build/k3b/CalendarIcsAdapter/libIcsJ2se/build/reports/tests/index.html
```

However i have no access to this file because it is on the build server so i cannot find out wich test failed and why.

when i run gradle in debug mode

```
./gradlew -d assemble libIcsJ2se:test
```

I see this in the log what i want:

```
07:06:56.713 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger] de.k3b.calendar.DtoIcRegressonsTests > shouldBeSameFixThisEvent STARTED
07:06:56.713 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger] 
07:06:56.713 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger] de.k3b.calendar.DtoIcRegressonsTests > shouldBeSameFixThisEvent FAILED
07:06:56.714 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]     org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:

<...
TART:20000502T123456
[DTEND:20000502T171234]
SUMMARY:test title
...> but was:<...
TART:20000502T123456[Z
DTEND:20000502T171234Z]
SUMMARY:test title
...>
07:06:56.717 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at de.k3b.calendar.DtoIcRegressonsTests.shouldBeSameFixThisEvent(DtoIcRegressonsTests.java:482)
```

However the gradle debug output contains many more details unrelated to junit-tests.

Is there a way to add only the details of the failed junit4 tests to gradle output witout making all of gradle more verbose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the [documentation of `TestLoggingContainer`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.logging.TestLoggingContainer.html) to see how to configure what is logged when running tests.

Comment: I had the similar problem as OP and haven't found good explanation in the docs on how to "add only the details of the failed junit4 tests to gradle output without making all of gradle more verbose".

Comment: Why not? It's right at the top of that link. Besides that failed tests are shown by default for me anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Set `showStandardStreams` to `true`.
I had a similar problem with gradle swallowing lots of test details, eg WebClient and Selenium

Example working configuration for JUnit5 will be:

```
test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    testLogging {
        showStandardStreams = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `showStandardStreams` gives too many details. Overriding [`exceptionFormat`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.logging.TestLoggingContainer.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.logging.TestLoggingContainer:exceptionFormat) is what you need.

```
import org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.logging.TestExceptionFormat
// ...
tasks.test {
    //...
    testLogging {
        exceptionFormat = TestExceptionFormat.FULL
    }
}
```